# How can I use xpath with or condition

Tags: xpath

I have elements on both the xpath

1. `//DIV[@class='sumFoot']/SPAN[4]`
2. `//DIV[@class='sumFoot']/SPAN[3]`

My desired element is sometimes on 1st xpath and sometimes on 2nd xpath
How can I choose xpath for element which is actually visible on website using both the xpath conditions...

Answer (score 3):

You can't determine which element is visible using XPath only. In case, by *"How can I use xpath with or condtion"*, you simply mean to get all the spans, be it in position `3` *or* `4`, the following XPath will do :

```
//DIV[@class='sumFoot']/SPAN[position()=3 or position()=4]
```